# Activity or service in background task?

Tags: android, interface, service, android-activity

Here's my set-up; I have a news app. This app loads a few listviews from local storage (I'm abusing sharedpreferences for that, but if that's good practice would be another question). I want to be able to update this local storage smoothly.

My first approach was to make a button trigger a service, which did the trick. But I also wanted the service to refresh the activity when it was done. I wasn't able to do that.
My current approach seems to work, but not as smoothly on 3G. Activity A shows a 'Loading' box, then launches activity B and destroys itself. Activity B also shows a loading box, does the downloading, then destroys itself and relaunches activity A with the new content.
However, this last approach makes the screen go black for a few seconds in transition from A to B when on 3G.

For the sake of visual smoothness, I'd like one loading popup to display continuously. When done, the activity should be refreshed.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

I hope my explanation was clear enough. Otherwise, I'd be happy to share some code with you.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Without code, it is hard to know what the problem is.

Comment: The issue is the 'lag' between activities, caused by activity B to be too heavy. Here's activity B: http://pastebin.com/3akrHtBa (Sorry for the Dutch comments :D) EDIT > I'm not looking to make activity B lighter (though it would be a side benefit), but I'm looking to make the UI smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you linked to in your comment, you are doing too much work in the `onCreate` method of your activity.  `onCreate` should be kept lightweight in order to display UI to the user as quick as possible.  You probably want to move the bulk of your `Activity` setup to the `onResume` method.  Furthermore, anything that blocks the UI thread (like fetching and parsing data) should be done on a thread.  Look at using `AsyncTask` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for this purpose in your application.

Comment: I can try this later and will mark as complete if this actually solves the lag. +1 regardless because it's definitely better.